# Trying to use aws-graphexplorer as a visualizer for local gremlin server does not store boolean values

Tags: docker, amazon-neptune, gremlin-server, graph-explorer

I was trying to connect graph explorer to gremlin server. I made the changes as per the connections.md docs.
Change gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager and gremlin.tinkergraph.edgeIdManager in /conf/tinkergraph-empty.properties to support string ids. You can use ANY
As soon as i did this my graph was unable to save boolean values. I changed it back to default but then graph explorer wouldn't read it. Also this resulted in my edges not being created.

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph
gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=ANY
gremlin.tinkergraph.edgeIdManager=ANY
```

in tinkergraph-empty.properties

OS: Windows 10
Browser: Google Chrome
Graph Explorer Version: 1.5.1
Graph Database & Version: gremlin server 3.7.0
First I need that changing the default values to ANY should not impact how the graph used to behave originally and save data originally and secondly, it should connect to graphexplorer and display everything correctly.

Comment: Those settings have to do with the ID values used for a vertex or and edge.  I don't think I've ever tested using booleans for IDs, nor would I ever want to do that.  IDs must be unique across all vertices and edges, so using booleans would only allow for a two vertices and two edges.  

Can you provide some detail on how you're loading data into your graph?